# SP-initiated Single Logout not working with SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, saml

I am attempting to use SP-initiated SLO with SalesForce (trying Redirect and POST) with the following LogoutRequest:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_1583fa34b3e9426ba5885849204d6f8d" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-11-14T18:42:25Z" Destination="https://myorg-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/auth/idp/saml2/logout">
  <saml:Issuer>myorg</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">me@myorg</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

I am using my SP entity ID for Issuer. I also tried using it for NameID SPNameQualifier. My Redirect and POST logic work for AuthnRequest. This SLO is working with OneLogin.

The error I get back is:

> We are unable to log you out. Please contact your administrator for
>   more information.

I can not find any relevant log entries.

Answer (score 1):

Which tool are you using to generate the XML?
Add the tag SessionIndex, which you can get from the login.

Comment: I am generating it more or less by hand. SessionIndex is not present in the Response AuthnStatement. I thought that was usually more relevant to SOAP bindings.